# How to add a File in vstemplate in a back folder?

Tags: c#, vsix, project-template, visual-studio-templates

i have a vsix (project template) currently i can add my file into a folder:

```
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName=".github\workflows\workflow.yml">workflow.yml</ProjectItem>
```

however, above code output is:

```
Project
   App.sln
   AppFolder
      .github
          workflows
               workflow.yml
```

but i want to put .github folder one step back:

```
Project
   App.sln
   .github
      workflows
          workflow.yml
   AppFolder
```

how i can do this?